# Managed Property is not Displayed for a List Column issue in SP 2013 Search Serv Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, managed-property, refiner

i have created  few splist columns in my  publishing site collection and went for full crawl in my custom search  service application.created a new content source.
Now I wanna configure the managed properties / crawled properties such that, i will be using this in my search center's results.aspx page's left side as Refiners.

But the newly created list columns [ NOT SITE COLUMNS ] names were not appearing in the search schema / managed properties.
What may be the reason for these columns disappearance?
i have added few items int this new `splist` and done `full crawl` multiple times.

Also restarted the `sp search service`, `sp timer service`, and `sp admin service`.
But all these actions are in vain . I need to get this working by seeing the **mycolumn1owstxt** kind of managed property.

Answer (score 2):

You indicate you are expecting to see **mycolumn1owstext**. That is an Automatic Managed property. They only appear when you use Site Columns.

You should see the Crawled Property **ows_mycolumn1** following a full crawl. Then you can manually create a Managed Property of any name you like.

Comment: i have used a doc lib column and not site column. so i thought the managed property column generated after full crawl will be having this mycolumn1owstext format. but even in the  cralwed property or managed property i am unable to see the column with ows_mycolumn1. amy problem with the search serv appln ? i did a index reset and performed a  full crawl again, but that also failed!

Comment: i have tested again with a new SPLIsT, with newly created  2 columnsand added some value and performed full crawl in my srch serv appln. but the crawled properties are NOT getting generated. At the same time, when i created a new document library and created 3 columns and uploaded a few documents into the doc lib with filled in metadata, and performed the full crawl , the doclib columns are appearing in the crawled properties, starting with ows_mycolumn1 . so there must be some problem with SPLIST thats not getting crawled by SP search engine. is there any resolution for this?

Comment: Is the list in the same web as the doc library? Are you certain that the list is crawlable? Check the Crawl Logs, the URL for the list should be there. If not you need to troubleshoot the crawl.

Comment: Yes, I have created the doc lib & splist in the same web its in my root web. I didn't check the crawl logs yet!

Comment: how to make the LIST IS CRAWLABLE? In the splist settings, i have ,made it as "YES" for the search settings  of the lists's advanced settings --> **allow items from this list to appear in search results** Will there be any time delay for generating index / search contents or creating managed properties in a sp farm? will it take many hours or days to update the crawl db / and fetch data from crawl and populate the results in the search serv appln page ?

Comment: i got error in the crawl errors: Error in the Microsoft SharePoint Server People Protocol Handler. " **Could not find stored procedure 'Search_GetRepositoryTimePerCrawl'**"

Comment: Ordinarily the lists are crawlable by default. Once you set it just do another full crawl. Let me know what you find once you get the crawl worked out.

Comment: yes, i have created another splist and with testlistcolumns and done a full  crawl but still, i was getting the above error, but with few articles already mentioned about the above error by Wictor etc , i got the fix for that error and ran the timer job and it the error went off. Now i ran the full crawl and this time , the crawl is sucessfull and no errors.But in the ows properties section, there was no mentioning of newly created splist column , ie, ows_testsbulistcolumn1.

Comment: My doubt, is if this kind if behaviour appears in this env, should i  create a  new search serv appln and perform all the steps again?its been created long back- 5 months before - after that, several installations performed on this farm.ie,workflow manager,SP2 upgrade etc . Am having WFE and SQL server separated .  my doubt is, whether all these installations, configurations might have done something on this already  existing search serv, appln?its  strange that, newly created document library columns were perfectly working and showing in the cralwed properties section-eg:ows_testdoclibcolumn1

Comment: If that is an option, sure. But it is rather drastic.